# How to get an AJAX call in component's administrator side

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, ajax, mvc, json

I added a component to my site and it accesses my DB via an AJAX call.  In my 'tmpl' folder, I have a 'default.php' file which makes an AJAX call that is received by `view.json.php` just outside that folder.  I really struggled to made that work, but I got it running by following the [Developing an MVC Component documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component).

Now I want to do the same thing with my administrator part. I have a `helloworld.php` file inside my administrator > components > com_helloworld and I want to make an AJAX request.  However, adding a `view.json.php` next to that file doesn't catch the AJAX call. The administrator files look like this:
[component administration side files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fznlP.png)

and it doesn't work using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "#",
    data: {
        [token]: "1",
        task: "savetasks",
        format: "json",
        json: valuesJson
    },
    success: (html) => {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: (err) => { 
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

But the same thing when done in the 'site' side works perfectly; the files look like this: [component client side files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lYZO.png)

The only real difference is that on the administrator side, I call the AJAX from `helloworld.php` and in the client I call it from `default.php`.

The way I get my AJAX call in the frontend is by using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '#',
    data: {
        [token]: "1", //i have the token saved in an input at the page just like the tutorial.
        task: "AnythingIInsertHereWorks",
        format: "json",
        json: stuffIWantToPass
    },
    success: (html) => { 
        //i do stuff on success here
    },
    error: (err) => { //alert error
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

And I get this at the `view.json.php` file. The tutorial says it goes there because it is waiting to catch a JSON request, which I'm sending. The task name in the AJAX call can be whatever and the token I am saving in an input at the page. This works fine, in my `view.json.php` file I do stuff like:

```
$json = ($_POST['json']);

$user = JFactory::getUser();

$id = ($user->id);

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "insert into user_task values $json on duplicate key update id = values(id), user_id = 
values(user_id), task_id = values(task_id), completed = values(completed), enabled = values(enabled), 
supplier = values(supplier)";

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

This way the user can change inputs on the front-end and when they click save, I call this AJAX to save things into the tables I created. And this does the job. I don't understand, however, how do I do the same thing on the administrator?

I have the html with inputs and such on my `helloworld.php` file in the administrator part, just like shown. I get stuff from the DB and show it on the page as normal using `$db = JFactory::getDbo();` and such. I don't really know how to save into the database from there. I just want to use AJAX to save the data that the administrator edited and wants to save. But adding a `view.json.php` file in there doesn't "catch" the AJAX json call. I don't want to use a standard form submission since I don't want to reload the page.

I hope this question is not confusing. I can give any other pieces of code and such.

I've asked the same question in [the Joomla! forums](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=727&t=980901) and on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62758357/8239042), but didn't manage to solve it yet.

This is Joomla! 3.x as far as I'm aware. Also if someone would be so kind, I could join a voice chat in discord or other.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] and consider telling us a bit about your exposure to Joomla when editing your profile.